# Javascript math recursive function optimisation

Tags: javascript, recursion, math

This is what I've got

```js
let base = 10000
let yearly = 31557600
let apy = 0.09

let loop = 0;
let new_base = '0';
function recurse(base){
    new_base = base*(1+apy*1/(yearly));
    if(loop < 3600){
        loop++;
        return recurse(new_base);    
    }
    else {
        return new_base;
    }
}
base = recurse(base);
console.log(base);
```

if I change 3600 by a very large number I get the error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This seems normal to me because the recursive operation is executed too many times,

what would be the solution ? Is it possible to transform the recursive function into a linear function for example?

Thanks

Comment: This recursive function is a simple for loop in disguise. `for(let i = 0; i < 3600; i++){new_base = new_base *(1+apy*1/(yearly));}`

Comment: Unclear why you would need recursion for this since there is nothing recursive about this.

Comment: In Chrome the maximum call stack size is around 10k. If you want to be doing high-performance functions like this you probably shouldn't be using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it can be transformed to an equation, but not a linear one.

Here, is the approach:

I will rename the base as b0, and the new base as b1

b1 = b0 * (1 + (apy/yearly)

and after loop is incremented new base will be updated, let's call the new b1 as b2:

b2 = b1 * (1 + (apy/yearly))

b2 = b0 * (1 + (apy/yearly))^2

and so on..

so the final returned value will be:

base * (1 + (apy/yearly))^3600

and the general formula will be

base * (1 + (apy/yearly))^n, where n is 3600 in your case.

Putting the constants plugged in you will get
10,000.102669931423184360664719158

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know how to write base * (1 + (apy/yearly))^n in javascript ?

Comment: Yes, thanks to javascript we can use `**`. So the equation will be written as, base*(1+(apy/yearly))**n. And FYI python also supports `**` for exponentiation. And please remember to upvote the answer as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you need recursion? No.

```
function recurse2(base){
    new_base = base*(1+apy*1/(yearly));
    for(loop = 1; loop < 100; loop++){
        new_base = base*(1+apy*1/(yearly));
    }
    return new_base;
}
```

You don't even tail optimization. This is just a value that is being mutated over and over. You don't need a new stackframe (function call) to mutate said value, just loop over it.

How did I arrive at this function? Just think what happens to the `base` when you pass it in and how it changes with each "recursion". It just gets multiplied by some expression each time. So we can just do that in a loop.

You can even improve the code snippet that I have here with a `do {} while();`

The following screenshot shows quick tests that show that function recurse2 that I wrote is identical*.
[image]